# Windows Mobile thread scheduling

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-mobile, focus, telephony

I have an issue about Windows Mobile thread scheduling: I have an application (C#) that detects incoming calls on the telephone. It is said that the operating system is "fully multitasking and multithreaded".

Still, I can detect an incoming call, but after the call is detected, the system application, showing that there is a call incoming, takes over the focus.My application doesn't get to execute itself until the system window (with the call) is deactivated. (something happens with the call).

Is there anything I can set so that my thread (application) executes even when the system window is focused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All solutions you can come up with for this are based on one thing: a hack. Windows Mobile is not meant to be customized as you wish - Windows CE is. You cannot override the default Windows Mobile phonecall UI, but you can put your own app above it with the correct API calls. However, it will flicker and it will look like s...t.

Comment: does it really mean that when the default phonecall UI is focused, my application does not get executed, is it completely frozen? I can observe that in the emulator, my application gets executed, even when the default phonecall UI is focused.

Comment: Of course it's executing in the background. It's not iOS. The shell just special treats the phone UI and you need to hack your way around that to lift your app UI to the top while keeping the phone UI away. While dirty and possible, WM was never meant for it, but CE was.

Comment: I'll test my application on a real device, again. Last time I tested it on the device, it seemed to be frozen, hope I was wrong. I do not necessary need the UI, so it can run in background. Thanks for the help!